# Парсинг сайта с помощью Curl php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Не могу никак парсить сайт.
Есть сайт , с помощью формы отправляет запрос на адрес XXXX.com/api/freeCheck

Сам запрос

```html
Request URL: https://XXXX.com/api/freeCheck
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 157.245.XXXX.52:22222
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: ru-RU
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 25 May 2020 17:04:20 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
vary: accept-encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-CSRF-HEADER: X-CSRF-TOKEN
X-CSRF-PARAM: _csrf
X-CSRF-TOKEN: d88f4a0a-2ad9-4c96-97af-546646288ba9
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: __stripe_mid=5d13abd8-99fc-4ad9-8064-10ee7219e16e; _ga=GA1.2.619486586.1590350326; _gid=GA1.2.788419123.1590350326; rhid_c=70898422597; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=0; JSESSIONID=FBDDC9495638DD9057F61B7FBC5B715B; __stripe_sid=cac61173-ed92-4a72-a1ed-67e2e4a7bfee; _gat_gtag_UA_165122012_1=1
Host: imei360.com
Origin: https://XXXX.com
Referer: https://XXXX.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
X-CSRF-TOKEN: d88f4a0a-2ad9-4c96-97af-546646288ba9
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Request payloader:
{imeiSerialNumber: "353136100436XXXX"}
imeiSerialNumber: "353136100436XXXX"
```

Comment: что значит  не могу никак парсить сайт? что именно не получается.

Comment: Вот не могу понять что не так , после отправки Curl приходит просто ничего. Пустая страница